# Login form is not working using php mysqli json

Tags: php

i have madea a simple login form along with the session. when i enter the username and password inorder to login the system. i didn't get any error but Login is not working. if i enter the correct username and password it didn't go the index.php and if i enter wrong username and password didn't show the errror message . if i look at the console error didn't show.

```
**Form Design**
<form id="frmlogin">
    <div class="form-group">   
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">    
    </div>

    <div id="err">    
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">    
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" onclick="login()">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQuery validation**

```
function login() {
    var data = $("#frmlogin").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validate_login.php',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 1) {
                window.location.replace('index.php');
            }
            else if (response == 3) {

                $("#err").hide().html("Email or password incorrect. Please check").fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else if (response == 0) {
                $("#passerr").hide().html("Account is not activated. please contact Administrator").fadeIn('slow');
            }

        }

    });
}
```

**validate_login.php**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    session_start();
    include("db.php");
    $uname=$_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,username,password from login WHERE username=? and password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $uname,$password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$username,$password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

        if ($stat==0){//invert of this
            echo 0;//email not verified
        }else{
            $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
            $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
            echo 1;
        }
    } else {
        echo 3;//use pass incorrect
    }

    $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: - Check console log
- Turn on error reporting
- Check network request It has to show some errors.

Comment: i did that but no errors show network request how to check

Comment: On chrome inspect element --> Network tab.
Check if there is request sending?

Comment: [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

Comment: this is the error displayed at console

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give action method in form tag. Add form method="post"